# Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked

Tags: linux, debian, mount, root, fstab

I have a Debian 11 that i was using LVM for data only, i did the following commands:

```
mount /dev/srv-vg/lv-data /mnt/data
vi /etc/fstab
/dev/srv-vg/lv-data /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 0
```

The mount command worked pretty well, the folder works just fine but after adding the fstab line when i reboot i get the following errors:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /mnt/data
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems

Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked
Press ENTER to continue
```

When i press enter, it just says the same message again (Root account is locked.)

Can someone help me?

Edit: Fixed typo.

Comment: Boot from external harddisk or USB stick, change back `/etc/fstab`. Alternatively take out harddisk, attach to other computer, mount, edit `/etc/fstab`. Also note you wrote `defauts` instead of `defaults` (not sure if that's a type in this question only).

Comment: Always add non-essential mounts with `nofail` option.

Comment: Hello. Its a type in this question only, the original one had defaults... Also, i did that. I booted from USB stick and tried mouting /root, edited /etc/fstab and it WORKED!! Thanks a LOT @dirkt If you answer below i can mark your answer as the solution. Also thanks Nikita, i will remember this option from now on to add for non-essential mounts... Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boot from external hard disk or USB stick, change back `/etc/fstab`. Alternatively, take out hard disk, attach it to another computer, mount, edit `/etc/fstab`.

And I second the comment to add `nofail` for non-essential mounts.