# can not open access to console the root account is locked (kali linux)

Tags: kali-linux, root

when I start my computer, I have this message:
*can not open access to console the root account is locked*

I had a quick check on the web and I found this:
[How to fix "can not open access to console the root account is locked"](https://gist.github.com/gnh1201/ef8fd8b7aa7ba1f76708d2e701ae25a5)

what I did:

1. Download SystemRescueCD and make a bootdisk
2. FDISK and MOUNT:

`# fdisk -l    # find a drive`

`# mkdir /mnt/tmp`

`# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/tmp`

3. Open the [mountpoint]/etc/fstab in text editor

Here is a picture of the file /etc/fstab:
[image: my /etc/fstab]

I don't really know which line to comment (everything seems ok). The only think I did is commenting the first one (#UUID=f08d3d7e...).

Then I reboot and I can log with a minimalist shell:

[image: minimalist shell]

I can `sudo su` but the files are only readable and I can not do any upgrade or do anything useful.

To make the files writable, I do `mount -o remount,rw /` and doing that, the shell disappears and I have a black screen.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684169/cannot-open-access-to-console-the-root-account-is-locked)

Comment: Hello Henrik, no I already read this post and it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever relying on troubleshooting instructions from an internet search or ChatGPT, you should always think about two things first:

- What is the actual issue these instructions are supposed to fix?
- Is it plausible that the issue the writer of the instructions had also applies to me? Are all the relevant conditions the same?

Never just blindly follow some instructions because they happen to have a similar error message as the one you're seeing at the moment.

Your system is trying to drop to rescue mode, because some systemd unit that has a dependency of type "required" is failing. But because direct logins to root account are disabled, it cannot prompt for root password, and allowing just anyone to access the system would not be secure at all.

Note that [the webpage you linked in the question](https://gist.github.com/gnh1201/ef8fd8b7aa7ba1f76708d2e701ae25a5) says:

> This problem is related to the change of the drive.

Unfortunately, that is not quite correct: while changing disk drives on your system without updating `/etc/fstab` to match the new configuration **is** one way to cause your original issue, but it is **not the only way** to cause that. Anything that causes a systemd unit that has a dependency of type `required` to fail at boot time can cause the system to attempt to drop to rescue mode. If the rescue mode is configured to provide root login on the system console, and Kali's default configuration has the root account locked, that is clearly a bug in how the rescue mode is configured to work; it makes the rescue mode useless.

Your `/etc/fstab` apparently has references to only one disk and one CD-ROM drive, so unless you have recently made changes to any of the first three partitions on your `/dev/sda` disk, **the solution in the webpage you linked was probably not applicable to your situation**.

So, you apparently commented out the `/etc/fstab` line referring to your root filesystem. And now the system apparently drops into emergency mode instead. But at least you can now log in and become root.

In emergency mode, one of the standard first steps is to get the root filesystem to read/write mode, so that you can begin fixing whatever is wrong. As root, you can do this with:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

But if that results in an error message, you may need to run a manual filesystem check on your root filesystem instead. Since your root filesystem type is `ext4`, the command would be:

```
fsck.ext4 -C0 /dev/sda2
```

If the filesystem check says "the filesystem was modified" at the end, then you should reboot before doing anything else, since the kernel may have already cached some data from the root filesystem. If that data contains any of the errors the filesystem check just fixed, you don't want to risk getting the root filesystem to read/write mode and possibly cause the kernel to write those errors right back in.

If the filesystem check found nothing to fix, or the root filesystem switched to read/write mode with no errors, the next step would be to start figuring out what exactly failed to cause the system to need to drop into rescue mode in the first place. `systemctl status` and `systemctl list-units --state=failed` might be very useful commands at this point. You might also want to scroll through the `dmesg -H` output to see if there are any errors.

If you cannot find any other failures while still in emergency mode and the root filesystem in read/write mode, you might consider enabling the root account so you don't get stuck the same way again:

```
usermod -e -1 root
passwd root
```

The first command will ensure the root account won't be locked by the expiration mechanism, and the second will set a new password for the root account, unlocking it in the process. Make the password a hard-to-guess one, in case the system becomes connected to network while the root account is still enabled. Note that in emergency mode, your keyboard may be using an US English default layout instead of whatever layout you normally prefer.

After that, you might uncomment the `/etc/fstab` line you commented out and try rebooting again. If the system now boots normally, remember to lock the root account again:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the same with a kali-live usb instead SystemRescueCD.

`mount -o remount,rw /` was ok that time and I was able to make an update!

Thank you everyone for your help!